# Single quote handling in a SQL string

Tags: c#, sql, .net, escaping

I have an application where the values in the text field are sent to the database.

For example I have a form with one field (text box). When I press Ok button then the content of the text field is inserted as a record into a table. I'm just trimming and extracting the text box's text into variable and passing it to my SQL string.

The problem is that whenever something like "It's" or "Friend's" the single quote is identified as the end of string. In Delphi I have seen something like `QuotedString` to avoide this. Any ideas from you?

Comment: are you using parameterised queries?

Comment: While you can safely just quote strings, you should use parameterized queries as Mitch suggests.

Comment: @Gabe: I'm guessing he will settle for the answer to his question, rather than addressing the real problem. SQL Injection here we come!!!!

Comment: Mitch: Assuming SQL Server, I don't think there are any SQL injection possibilities if *all* strings are properly quoted. Of course, people have the habit of routinely not properly quoting every string, improperly leaving things that they expect to be dates or numbers unquoted.

Comment: @Mitch : yeah I get ur point... Thanks

Comment: @Gabe : yep. it only takes one or two to slip through and it's "helloo little bobby tables!"

Comment: @Gabe : also you have to escape for LIKE clauses....!

Comment: Mitch: If you're talking about escaping `%` inside `LIKE` patterns, that has nothing to do with SQL injection and has to be done manually even with parameterized queries.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Don't ever build SQL statements like that, it's very unsafe [(read this)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use parameters, i.e:

```
var command = new SqlCommand("select * from person where firstname = @firstname");
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@firstname";
param.Value         = "testing12'3";
command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: What I am doing is a very simple app. That's why I didn't use this.Thanks Alot anyway.

Comment: @JCTLK: do it the right way. small app.s of a habit of becoming bigger ones if they are found to be useful. Also, keep your code base full of patterns that should be copied, NOT patterns that are undesirable.

Comment: @JCTLK: This is hardly complicated, and has *huge* benefits in the longer term.

Comment: It can even be condensed down to 1 line to add a param: command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", "testing12'3");

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - Yep. I should also have noted that it will work out the SqlDbType from the .NET as best it can (e.g. strings will always get passed in as NVARCHAR). My pref is to always be explicit with db types + sizes.

Comment: Question... When I do this the apostrophe still destroys my Oracle stored proc... Am I missing something here... Should the parameter name always have the @ symbol in front of this?  I am using ODP.net btw...

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Replace("'","''''")`

For example

```
string name = txtName.Text.Replace("'","''''");
```

Now `name` can be passed as a parameter in stored procedure etc.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help you ...

```
public static string DoQuotes(string sql)
    {
        if (sql == null)
            return "";
        else
            return sql.Replace("'", "''");
    }
```

Comment: Deleting comments here - they've got out of hand and attracted **lots** of flags - some enough flags to trip automatic removal. Summary: *lots* of people think that the quote-based approach here is an exceptionally bad idea when parameters are just as easy, and much more robust. Others (OK, the OP) disagree.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a more robust treatment for how to handle quotes in those circumstances where parameterization is - for whatever obscure reason - truly not possible.

Comment: This method works well for small personal applications where SQL Injection is not a concern.