# Handle apostrophe in strings

Tags: c#, sql

I want to handle special characters in data rows. Some of the columns have string that contain an apostrophe in it and it fails while saving these records. Here is an example: `the UK's premier`  I wanted to know the best way to handle all the special characters in C#.

Comment: That's not a comma, it's an apostrophe. And that shouldn't cause a problem if you are forming your SQL statement correctly using parameters, rather than string concatenation

Comment: Is this `"а"` (Cyrilic a) special for you too? Defining "special" may give the question a chance to be ok.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Single quote handling in a SQL string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644703/single-quote-handling-in-a-sql-string)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I wanted to know the best way to handle all the special characters in C#

I assume then you're building a SQL statement in a method similar to this:

```
string SQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name = '" + strName + "'";
```

For various reasons (protection against SQL injection, freedom from having to deal with special characters, etc.), you should use parameters instead:

```
string SQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name = @Name";
command.Parameters.Add("@Name").Value = strName;
```

Comment: Just being nitpicky, but you don't have to include the `@` when adding the parameter.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt True, but old habits are hard to break, and there's no harm in including it that I'm aware of.

Comment: Right you are -- they're functionally equivalent. I just couldn't miss the chance to nitpick.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is your using inline SQL statements to add your data.

Switch to [parametized queries](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) to resolve this issue, and prevent [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327/).